# Google Maps Geocoding API (How to get Lat/Long)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I'm developing a Web application that interacts with maps, so I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API (v3.0).

The application will have a search box (an HTML `<input>` tag) where users can enter human-readable place names (like "19/2 Pine Street, Seattle") and hit a button. The input should be sent to Google Maps API and it should return the Geo-location (latitude and longitude) of the search place.

I have searched through the Google Maps API documentation but everything is too mixed up there. I was hoping if anybody could help me with a custom solution.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo Rails App</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key-here]"></script>
    <script>
    var geocoder;
    function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    function codeAddress() {
      var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(r, s) {
        alert(r[0].geometry.location);
      });
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <input type="search" id="address">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned Geocoding API so I guess you have read through the documentation. What have you struggled with trying it so far?

Comment: @TaoP.R. Currently the code takes the search input and alerts the predicted lat/long. But I need the autocomplete feature as well (as in typing, it shows a list of places as suggestions). Like in this example: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-searchbox

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete Everything is there.

Comment: Your posted code works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nxuctern/) (both with and without the map))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key-here]">you forgot to close the script tag</script>
```

here's why it doesn't work

edit: autocomplete, a little something I just threw together

```
googlePlaceSearch = function (qry, callback) {
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var addressParts = {
        street_number: '',
        route: '',
        locality: '',
        administrative_area_level_1: '',
        country: '',
        postal_code: ''
    };
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };
    var fillInAddress() {
        placeSearch.style.display = 'none';
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place) {
            place.address_components.forEach(function (comp) {
                var addressType = comp.types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    addressParts[addressType] = comp[componentForm[addressType]];
                }
            });
        }
        callback(addressParts);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.querySelector(qry)), {
        types: ['address']
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', fillInAddress);
};
```

initiate using

```
googlePlaceSearch("#address", someFn);
```

where #address is a CSS selector to target the input element (easy in your case, it's as I put it, #address, but I've thrown this together to be flexible), and someFn is a function that receives `addressParts` so you can do what you want with the returned address

Comment: Oops! That was a mistake. But I still need the autocomplete feature.

Comment: Oh FFS - I put together a generic autocomplete and in the meantime you anwer your own question :p

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found the solution:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key-here]&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
function codeAddress() {
  var input = document.getElementById("address");
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(r, s) {
    alert(r[0].geometry.location);
  });
}
</script>
```

and HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <input type="search" id="address">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress()">
</body>
```